# Generate array of datetime.time object python

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, time

How can I generate an array of `datetime.time` objects from these two objects:

```
start = datetime.time(22, 0)
end   = datetime.time( 2, 0)
```

That will look like:

```
interval = array([datetime.time(22,0), datetime.time(23,0), datetime.time(0,0),
                  datetime.time( 1,0), datetime.time( 2,0)])
```

**EDIT**

In this example the delta is hour=1, but it might be minutes or seconds. I'm loking for something similar to `pandas.date_range`.

Comment: This looks like you want a `list`, not an `array`.

Comment: Typo in the edit ('loking').

Answer (score 1):

**update** shorter version with numpy

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

def return_times(start,end):
    if start < end:
        return np.array([datetime.time(i,0) for i in range(start.hour,end.hour+1)])
    else:
        hours = list(range(24))
        nplist = np.array([datetime.time(i,0) for i in hours if i not in list(range(end.hour+1,start.hour))])
        return np.roll(nplist, -np.where(nplist==start)[0][0])

return_times(datetime.time(0,0),datetime.time(3,0)) # if-case 1
return_times(datetime.time(22,0),datetime.time(2,0)) # else-case
```

00:00 -> 03:00

```
array([datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(1, 0), datetime.time(2, 0),
   datetime.time(3, 0)], dtype=object)
```

> 100000 loops, best of 3: 12.6 µs per loop

22:00 -> 02:00

```
array([datetime.time(22, 0), datetime.time(23, 0), datetime.time(0, 0),
       datetime.time(1, 0), datetime.time(2, 0)], dtype=object)
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 79.9 µs per loop

---

**update2** Using mod thanks to  SwiftsNamesake, this can be solved in a single list comprehension

```
import datetime

def return_times(start,end):
    s  = start.hour
    e  = end.hour 
    hours = [i%24 for i in range(s, e+1 if e >= s else 24+e+1)]
    return [datetime.time(i,0) for i in hours]

return_times(datetime.time(0,0),datetime.time(3,0))
```

> 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.75 µs per loop

Comment: This is a lot more complicated than it needs to be imo

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Yep, maybe you were right about that. Made a shorter version using numpy. At least it works :)

Comment: `[i%24 for i in range(s, e + 1 + (0 if e >= s else 24))]`

Comment: Good on ya for profiling the various solutions. +1 Just for that

Comment: One thing though: You can get rid of the intermediate list by using a generator comprehension.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Please tell where!

Comment: `hours = [...]`

Comment: Like this? Because it is not faster (but I guess more efficient?)) hours = (i%24 for i in range(s, e+1 if e >= s else 24+e+1))
type(hours) = generator ---- big thanks btw

Comment: Yes, the only syntactic difference between list and generator comprehensions are that the former uses parentheses instead of square brackets. Generators save *memory* compared to lists, so it's not surprising you didn't see a difference in execution speed.

Answer (score 1):

You could first generate the numbers you want with a kind of `modularRange` function. The generator expression makes the code shorter; we could've used a `for` loop, coupled with `yield`.

```
def modularRange(start, end, step, mod):
  return (i % mod for i in range(start, end + 1 + (0 if end >= start else mod), step))
```

You could also cheat a bit with the upper bound, exploiting the fact that `bool`s are `int`s at the core:

```
range(start, end + 1 + mod*(end < start)
```

The `mod` argument would be `24` in your case and `step` is `1` (hour).

You'd then use `np.array` to construct the array, as the other posters have shown.

```
np.array([datetime.time(hour,0) for hour in modularRange(start.hour, end.hour, 1, 24)])
```

---

The OP requested an example with minutes. The code below will generate `datetime.time` objects at 5-minute intervals. I had to amend the `modularRange` function to account for steps.

```
startMin = start.hour * 60 + start.minute # Convert to minutes
endMin   = end.hour   * 60 + end.minute   # Convert to minutes
np.array([datetime.time(mins//60, mins%60) for mins in modularRange(startMin, endMin, 5, 24*60)])
```

Comment: You didn't ask about minutes, but if you want an example, I'll edit my answer to cover it.

Comment: @LorenzoBottaccioli Edited

Comment: @LorenzoBottaccioli Does my answer address your question in full or is there anything else you'd like to know.

Answer (score 0):

> datetime.time([hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[, tzinfo]]]]]) --> a time object

So if you look out some `attributes` of `datetime.time` like

```
start.hour
>>> 22    
end.hour
>>> 2
start.max
>>> datetime.time(23, 59, 59, 999999)
start.max.hour
>>> 23
```

You can implement your `list` using above factor.

```
[datetime.time(i, 0) for i in range(start.hour, start.max.hour+1)] + [datetime.time(i, 0) for i in range(end.min.hour, end.hour+1)]
Out[157]: [datetime.time(22, 0), datetime.time(23, 0), datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(1, 0), datetime.time(2, 0)]
```

Comment: You don't have to create two separate lists.

Answer (score -1):

More simplistic solution can be

```
T = np.arange(datetime.date(2019, 4, 13),datetime.date(2020, 4, 13))
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.